# How do I split a string at a certain character?

Tags: delphi

How do I split a line of text (e.g., `Hello there*3`) into an array? Everything before the `*` needs to be added to the first element and everything after the `*` needs to be added to second. I'm sure this is possible. I need to recall this later on and the first and second items must have relation to each other

I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: Your example of 'a line' looks more like *three* lines, to me. Maybe you should clarify what the input and what the expected output is.

Comment: Which version of delphi are you using?

Comment: You are talking about 'multidimensional arrays', but your example suggests that you are only interested in a single-dimensional array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type
  TStringPair = array[0..1] of string;

function SplitStrAtAmpersand(const Str: string): TStringPair;
var
  p: integer;
begin
  p := Pos('&', Str);
  if p = 0 then
    p := MaxInt - 1;      
  result[0] := Copy(Str, 1, p - 1);
  result[1] := Copy(Str, p + 1);
end;
```

or, if you aren't into magic,

```
function SplitStrAtAmpersand(const Str: string): TStringPair;
var
  p: integer;
begin
  p := Pos('&', Str);
  if p > 0 then
  begin
    result[0] := Copy(Str, 1, p - 1);
    result[1] := Copy(Str, p + 1);
  end
  else
  begin
    result[0] := Str;
    result[1] := '';
  end;
end;
```

If you, for some utterly strange and slightly bizarre reason, need a procedure and not a function, then do

```
procedure SplitStrAtAmpersand(const Str: string; out StringPair: TStringPair);
var
  p: integer;
begin
  p := Pos('&', Str);
  if p > 0 then
  begin
    StringPair[0] := Copy(Str, 1, p - 1);
    StringPair[1] := Copy(Str, p + 1);
  end
  else
  begin
    StringPair[0] := Str;
    StringPair[1] := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @David: That is why I just fixed it, even before you sent your comment!

Comment: This is really sad, especially compared to how you need only one line for an extremely portable solution in Python: `'Hello there*3'.split('*')`

Comment: @BlaXpirit I actually think that modern delphi has a built in split

Comment: And say I don't want to use an ampersand, but an asterisk instead?

Comment: @noob: Then replace `'&'` by `'*'`.

Comment: BlaXpirit: what prevents you from writing a Python-like library with similar string functions? Syntax may be different, but the results and ease of use could be the same. Add also some of the OS X Foundation string functions, and you got something nice to work with. <g>

Comment: Can you perhaps change it to a procedure?

Comment: @noob: Why would you prefer it to be a procedure rather than a function?